# Building a connection between SQLite database and Xamarin.Android project using SQL/SQLite toolbox Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin.android, toolbox

I succeeded in importing a `SQLite` database using `SQL`/`SQLite` toolbox for my `Xamarin.Android` Project under Visual Studio 2019, However I can't seem to find a way to establish a connection between my database and the project... I looked everywhere for a connection string or any plugin that would help me do the task, but there wasn't enough documentation regarding the subject.
Does anyone have an idea that can help me make a progress?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this document [Using SQLite.NET with Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm).

Once you have the `SQLite.NET` library available, follow these three steps to use it to access a database:

1. **Add a using statement** – Add the following statement to the C# files
   where data access is required:

   ```
   using SQLite;
   ```
2. **Create a Blank Database** – A database reference can be created by
   passing the file path the SQLiteConnection class constructor. You do
   not need to check if the file already exists – it will automatically
   be created if required, otherwise the existing database file will be
   opened. The `dbPath` variable should be determined according the rules
   discussed earlier in this document:

   ```
   var db = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath);
   ```
3. **Save Data** – Once you have created a SQLiteConnection object,
   database commands are executed by calling its methods, such as
   CreateTable and Insert like this:

   ```
   db.CreateTable<Stock> ();
   db.Insert (newStock); // after creating the newStock object
   ```
4. **Retrieve Data** – To retrieve an object (or a list of objects) use the
   following syntax:

   ```
   var stock = db.Get<Stock>(5); // primary key id of 5
   var stockList = db.Table<Stock>();
   ```